# Xploder Xbox360 Minecraft Special Edition not recognising USB memory device

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, xbox-360

A couple of days ago a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/216126/xploder-xbox360-minecraft-special-edition) was asked* regarding why the Minecraft Special Edition Xbox 360 Xploder Software will not allow them to transfer game saves on PC to the saves on Xbox 360 storage device.

The error was, as it states:

> No Xbox 360 storage connected.

The reason I brought this up, is the exact same thing is happening to my son whom purchased this Special Edition Xploder disc for the Xbox 360, and has followed the instructions to the letter.

We have two 360's and three brand new USB disks (from different manufacturers). They have been duly formatted and are recognised by both consoles. They have even been tried at a friends property on three Xbox 360s and are all recognised as having profile saves, therefore the USBs are correctly formatted and are recognized by the 360s.

The Xploder software has been loaded on to a total of three laptops and a desktop now (after each failure), and each installed correctly with no difficulties and will download the game saves.

However on each of the PCs above, it will not allow the transfer of game saves to any USB as it states that *"NO XBOX 360 STORAGE CONNECTED"*.

The USBs are being used one at a time in each laptop and desktop with no other memory device or USB device inserted either so as to not "confuse" the software and still it does not recognise the memory device.

The failure is in the Xploder software not recognising there is a memory device connected and compatible with this software.

So if you can, I have a couple of questions:

1. Why doesn't the software recognise the memory device that has been correctly formatted?
2. Is there any way to make this software work as currently both my son and the other question's OP purchased a product that is not fit for purpose?
3. Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

<sub>* The question has since been deleted and is only viewable by those with >10k reputation)</sub>

Comment: Link to the mentioned question, in case someone is wondering (there were no answers, so adds nothing to this question): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/216126/xploder-xbox360-minecraft-special-edition

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Arquade, Jose. Thanks for taking the time to claridy the original question. Sometimes nobody happens to have the time to properly digest a question. (Especially if they are a solid block of text with not even a proper punctuation.) Unless the original poster comes back to make an effort to clarify the question, they risk getting forgotten.

Comment: Hi Jose. I've taken the liberty of editing your question to fit our format more: we generally don't link back to old questions unless they add something of value, whereas I think your question stands better on it's own: the other question didn't have much (if anything) to add to the point you were trying to make. :)

Answer (score 1):

The XBox uses a **FAT32** format system, whereas most PCs use **NTFS**. The two versions are way off in terms of update progress. Also, PC saves use a different storage system than XBox, having converted to Anvil storage quite a while ago.

Comment: Whilst most Windows PCs use NTFS for their operating system partition, it doesn't mean they can't recognise, read/write to and interpret FAT32.

Comment: @Robotnik you are correct, and I realize now that I worded that incorrectly, but what I meant is that the two update versions are totally incompatible. PC also uses a different save format.